# FLEX: can a Popup created with Pop-up manager be draggable?

Tags: apache-flex, flex3

I've created a TitleWindow with PopupManager and I was wondering if I can drag it over my Canvas

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Popup based on TitleWindow and Panel would be draggable by default.